# Why is "that" placed at the end of the sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-order

In *Tomb Raider (2018)*, Rog and Bill discussing about fox hunting i.e i.e person is supposed to carry a fox tail on the back of her bike while a team of bikers chase after them :

> Rog: Got 30 hounds signed up. Just gotta find a fox now.
>
> Bill: **Tough one, that**. Need someone quick enough to make it
>   interesting.
>
> Rog: Yeah. No fun if they ain't quick.

Why is "that" placed at the end of the sentence? Why can't written as **that is tough one**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variant is more grammatically and formally correct. The variant in the story is rather informal / colloquial, and definitely a literary construct.

It has the purpose to move the accent from "that" onto "tough one".